# how to add product to cart in magento api V2

Tags: magento-1.7, product, api, soap

I am trying to add product in to cart. I am facing lot of trouble with this. I have searched a lot of blogs. But could not find feasible answer.

I have also used the link in magento soap api v2 for [adding product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html).

Every time i am getting error

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1022] Please specify the
>   product required option(s).

Pls give  me a proper example that what are the input values should be there and what are their values..I am attaching my code here..

```
 <?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.magentohost.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
 $sessionId = $proxy->login('user', 'apikey'); 
 $resultCartId = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId, '1');
$productList = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
$product = (array) $productList[0];
$product['qty'] = 1;
$product['product_id'] = '234';
$product['sku'] = 'xxxxxxxx';
$product['name'] = 'abcdefgh';
$product['description'] = 'abcdefgh';
$product['short_description'] = 'abcdefgh';
$product['weight'] = '123.0000';
$product['status'] = '1';
$product['url_key'] = 'ab_cd_ef';
$product['url_path'] = 'ab_cd_ef.html';
$product['visibility'] = '2';
$product['tax_class_id'] = '1';
$product['price'] = '899.0000';
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, $resultCartId, array($product));
//var_dump($result);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: It looks like the product you are adding is either configurable or has some custom options. Have a look at the attributes you need to set on the product.

Answer (score 1):

you can add to cart a product.
But product have some option and it's mandatory. so your item will not set in cart. so first check the option of the cart or add new simple product and check it.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 $arrProducts = array(
                    array(
                        "product_id" => $productId,
                        "qty" => $qty
                    )
                );
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart_product_api')->add($quoteId,$arrProducts,$storeId) ;
```